# Cauchy Riemann using polar form of $f(z)$? (NOT polar form of $z$)

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Every time I search for a polar form of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, I find answers relating the derivatives of the real and complex parts of $f(z)$ to each other. That is: $\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial r} = \dfrac{1}r \dfrac{\partial v}{\partial \theta}$ and $\dfrac{1}r \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial \theta} = −\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial r}$.

This is emphatically **not** what I'm asking for. I mean the polar form of $f(z)$, that is:

$f(z)=r(z)e^{i\theta(z)}$

If you simply take the complex logarithm of both sides and take derivatives, it seems that:

$R_{90^{o}}[\frac{\nabla r(z)}{r(z)}] = \nabla \theta(z)$,

where $R_{90^{\circ}}$ is the rotation operator for $90$ degrees. Has anyone encountered this relation before? It's very useful for interpreting color-domain plots for example, if true. I just can't seem to find any name for this form of the C.R. equations.

Comment: *Hint*: You are just considering $\log\circ f\circ\exp$.

Comment: Hm? Aren't I rather considering $log(f(z))$ and just straightforwardly applying the Cauchy-Riemann equations?